# Java method selection with overloading and overriding

Tags: java, overloading, overriding, dynamic-binding, static-binding

I am having hard time to understand some principles about overriding and overloading.

```
public class Figure{
    public void stampa(Figure f){
        System.out.println("Figure");
    }
}
public class Square extends Figure{
    public void stampa(Square q){
        System.out.println("Square");
    }
}
public class Rectangle extends Square{
    public void stampa(Rectangle r){
        System.out.println("Rectangle");
    }
    public void stampa(Square r){
        System.out.println("Particular Rectangle");
    }
    public void stampa(Figure f){
        System.out.println("Particular Figure");
    }
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Figure f1,f2;
        Square q = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        f1 = new Square();
        f2 = new Rectangle();

        f1.stampa(f2); //Figure
        q.stampa(r); //Particular Rectangle 
        f1.stampa(q); //Figure
        q.stampa(f1); //Particular Figure 
        q.stampa(q); //Particupar Rectangle
    }
}
```

I know that     `public void stampa(Square q)` is overloading  `public void stampa(Figure f)` and not overrding it.

And  `public void stampa(Rectangle r)` and  `public void stampa(Figure f)` are also overloading  `public void stampa(Square q)`.

Also `public void stampa(Square q)` in Rectangle class is overriding the method in Square class.

**First question**

it's about this result : `q.stampa(f1); //Particular Figure` 
I know that at compile-time `q` is an `Square` so i will look at this method `public void stampa(Square q)`in `Square` class. and at run-time `q` is `Rectangle` so i thought the result might be "Particular Rectangle" instead of "Particular Figure"

Not sure what I'm doing wrong

**Second question**

If at this moment `Rectangle` extends `Figure` and not any more `Square`, I will certainly have compilation error on `Square q = new Rectangle();` what happens to the varibale `q` (there will be have such a variable as `Square q` or we dont have any varible with name q?) and what will be the result of `q.stampa(f1);`

Thanks and sorry for my english and please correct me if I'm wrong at some point.

Comment: Your class is defined as `Figura`. Unless this is just a copy and paste typo, this would create some problems.

Comment: @kunruh thanks, i fixed it

Comment: Besides your override/overload question, I would like to comment that the inheritance hierarchy is wrong, as a Rectangle is not a special Square, otherwise every rectangle would also be (is-a) a square, and this is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that at compile-time `q` is an `Square` so i will look at this method `public void stampa(Square q)`in Square class.

You're forgetting that `Square` contains *two* methods: `stampa(Square q)` and `stampa(Figure f)`. The latter is inherited from `Figure` and is selected at compile time as the <strike>most</strike> only appropriate overload.

> and at run-time `q` is Rectangle so i thought the result might be "Particular Rectangle" instead of "Particular Figure"

Overloads are selected at compile time, and overrides at runtime. As stated, `stampa(Figure f)` is already selected at compile time. Once it's actually invoked, the runtime sees that `q` is an instance of `Rectangle` and delegates the invocation to `Rectangle.stampa(Figure f)`.

As for the second question, I don't really understand what you're asking. A compile error means the code is invalid and nothing happens. `q.stampa(f1)` will never be called and will never return a result.

Answer (score 4):

First question:

`q`'s declared type is Square. `f1`'s declared type is Figure. So the compiler looks for a method named stampa, in the class Square and its superclasses, if a method accepting a Figure (or a superclass of Figure) exists. It finds onein Figure: `public void stampa(Figure f)`. At compile time, what matters is the declared type of the variable.

Now, at runtime, the actual runtime type of the object referred by `q` is examined: it's a Rectangle. So the runtime looks for a method `public void stampa(Figure f)` that overrides the Figure method, in Rectangle, and all its superclasses until Figure. That's what allows polymorphism. It finds one in Rectangle:

```
public void stampa(Figure f) {
    System.out.println("Particular Figure");
}
```

Second question:

You will indeed have a compilation error, so reasoning about the type of the variable q doesn't make sense: there will be no such variable, since the code does not compile, and the class is thus not generated by the compiler.